# upload to drop off library using CSOM documents not routing

Tags: csom, records-management, shareoint

Using PowerShell and CSOM, I'm able to upload to the Drop Off Library but the document never routes.  Working with SP2016 on-prem.

- Manually uploaded documents route correctly.
- CSOM uploaded documents will route only after I edit the properties and click save (no changes are made to the metadata).
- My account is in the Records Center Web Service Submitters group along with Site Owners.

Example of the script I'm working with:

```
        $FileStream = New-Object IO.FileStream($File.FullName,[System.IO.FileMode]::Open)
        $FileCreationInfo = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FileCreationInformation
        $FileCreationInfo.Overwrite = $true
        $FileCreationInfo.ContentStream = $FileStream
        $FileCreationInfo.URL = $File
        $Upload = $List.RootFolder.Files.Add($FileCreationInfo)

        $item = $Upload.ListItemAllFields
        $item["Router"] = "B" 
        $item.Update()
        $RemoteContext.Load($Upload)
        $RemoteContext.Load($item)
        $RemoteContext.ExecuteQuery()
```

Comment: Shot in the dark - is it going in as “checked out”?

Comment: Require checkout is disabled.

Comment: Yes but I’ve had files go in as checked out even when it is not required, especially if there is a required column.

Comment: Previously tried that with no luck.  Error:
"The file "DropOffLibrary/testUpload_0.txt" is not checked out."

Comment: Any mandatory fields missing? I know you said you changed nothing but checking anyway...

Comment: Nope, no mandatory fields.  If I upload a document using CSOM, then edit and save, the doc routes.  When doing the edit and save, I'm not making any updates to the fields.

Comment: as far as i know, CSOM won't work if you make things manually, you'll have to use an event receiver (SSOM) or a workflow

Comment: @Taco_Buffet did you wind up figuring out a solution? I'm running into the same problem

Comment: @athom not that i can remember.  i vengefully recall doing something along the lines of getting the routing rules, then using the info to route my my docs.  i no longer have access to the code, sorry.